# What is a Swiss Knife Word™?

Tags: word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Swiss Knife Word™***.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Swiss Knife Words ™ | Not Swiss Knife Words ™ |
| --- | --- |
| ORANGE | PEAR |
| MEET | MEAT |
| GO | CHESS |
| ANSWER | RESPONSE |
| PUZZLE | SOLUTION |
| ACCOUNT | USER |
| PLANT | BACTERIA |
| TRUMP | PRESIDENT |
| FIRE | FORGET |
| PHONE | COMPUTER |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Swiss Knife Words™,Not Swiss Knife Words™
ORANGE,PEAR
MEET,MEAT
GO,CHESS
ANSWER,RESPONSE
PUZZLE,SOLUTION
ACCOUNT,USER
PLANT,BACTERIA
TRUMP,PRESIDENT
FIRE,FORGET
PHONE,COMPUTER
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Swiss Knife Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Swiss Knife Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

$ $

Comment: That was the most important edit I have ever approved. Avoided catastrophe there!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

My humble guess:

> A Swiss Knife Word fits into more than one "class", while a Not Swiss Knife Word is of only one "class". A "class" is one of noun, verb, adjective, adverb etc. (part of speech).

Clarification:

> orange is N/A; pear is N-only
>  meet is N/V; meat is N-only
>  go is N/V; chess is N-only
>  answer is N/V; response is N-only
>  puzzle is N/V; solution is N-only
>  account is N/V; user is N-only
>  plant is N/V; bacteria is N-only
>  trump is N/V; president is N-only
>  fire is N/V; forget is V-only
>  phone is N/V; computer is N-only

It's called a Swiss Knife Word™ because

> just like a [Swiss Army Knife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Army_knife), it is capable of different functions.

More examples:

> Swiss Knife Word - Not Swiss Knife Word
>
> correct - incorrect
>  safe - danger
>  milk - coffee
>  stop - cease
>  stable - delicate

Comment: As for the correct term: https://bit.ly/36FkeGp (the link itself would spoil the solution)

Comment: @Glorfindel Isn't there a single word for this?

Comment: Not that I know of (not a native speaker either)

Comment: I would like to incorrect you in the matter of the first additional Not Swiss Knife Word.

Comment: @Bass. [What Wiktionary says](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incorrect).

Comment: Well, of course your answer is correct, that's why I wanted to incorrect it :-)

Comment: By this definition, meat would also be a swiss knife word, though somewhat rare. (ROT13: ihytne grez sbe ratntvat va pbvghf,  byq grez sbe srrq).  solution, forget and chess could also be Swiss Knife words.

Comment: I'm still puzzling my way through this one.

Comment: OK, so the Swissest Knife word is undoubtedly, "buffalo".

Comment: @MrLister Sort of?  But only if you count using the name of a city as an adjective.  Otherwise it's exactly as Swiss Knife-y as the rest of the examples.

Comment: No, it's the fourth "additional Not Swiss Knife Word™" that's wrong (_cease and desist_ - imperative verb; *without cease* - noun)

Answer (score 2):

> Words which have more than one meaning? Each word on the left contains more than common meaning, where as words on the right generally have two or more.  Although, does Trump?  Do names count in this context